# I am using Laravel Passport for my authentication, So how do I apply authetication in my application after receiveing the bearer token from the api

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

So this is a samle of the code that my api returns

```
  ▼
  +"status": true
  +"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImI0MjgxMjZhODJiMzFkMmZhYTg2NjdmZjBkZDFjY2FmNmQwMzJlMmViYzhiMWEwYmM3MTg5N2RlZTk3MjIzMzU0YjNjZGMwMWI5YjYzZjk2In0.eyJh ▶"
  +"token_type": "Bearer"
  +"expires_at": "2020-03-23 17:23:15"
}
```

My question is:how do I use apply this in my app ? Do I set a session and store the token or is there a "laravel way" of implemting it ?

Comment: you use the token to authorize API calls from the frontend. Laravel Passport helps you out of the box to authenticate your local API calls from your blade files (as a monolith, not Single Page Application). For other clients, there is no session involved, just put the token in the header 'Authorization: Bearer access_token'

Comment: Thank You @Alex so how do I store the token ?

Comment: please specify your client: is a SPA (the API is detached) or the Laravel monolith?